# create arraylist from function arguments

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have a very easy question, i need to create an array list from function arguments, so far i managed to alert them one by one, but can't create a list:

```
<span onclick="show_flights(1,2,3,4);">text</span>
```

and function

```
function show_flights() {
    var list='';
    for (var x = 0; x < arguments.length; x++) {
        alert(arguments[x]);
        list.append(arguments[x]);
    };
alert(list);
```

thank you everybody for help, i really appreciate it!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could just convert the `arguments` object directly to an array:

```
function show_flights() {
    var list = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 0);
    alert(list);
}
```

If you're interested in the details of how/why this actually works, have a read through the ECMAScript spec, in particular the section on the [`Array.prototype.slice`](http://es5.github.com/#x15.4.4.10) method. To sum it up very briefly, the method will attempt to create an array from the object on which it is called (its `this` value), by iterating over its properties and adding them to that new array (via the internal mechanism `[[DefineOwnProperty]]`).